# Ruby on Rails Installation, Ubuntu on Windows10 #<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)>

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sockets, ubuntu

I have installed Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu on Windows 10 following the instructions here: https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10

when I create the database (`rake db:create`) I receive the following error message twice:

```
User1@My-Macine:~/test1$ rake db:create 
#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"xxxxx", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"test1_development"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

My `config/database.yml` is the following:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: xxxxx
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test1_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test1_test


production:
  <<: *default
  database: test1_production
  username: test1
  password: <%= ENV['TEST1_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I also checked for `mysqld` dir and `mysqld.sock` file and they did not exist.
So, according other answers, I tried to create `mysqld` dir and restart `mysql`

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld/
sudo service mysql restart
```

The restart failed and received the following error message

```
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

I have checked solutions from similar cases/questions here but couldn't resolve it. 
Can you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it. I had also to create the `mysqld.pid` and `mysqld.sock` files inside the new created `mysqld` dir and restart `mysql`.
I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/980841/why-is-mysqld-pid-and-mysqld-sock-missing-from-my-system-even-though-the-val